# Cannot delete has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models

Subject

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :students, through: :enrollments, source: :students
```

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments, foreign_key: 'student_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subjects, through: :enrollments
```

Enrollment

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :student, class_name 'User'
```

Let say, first I do

```
User.count # return 23
```

It returns 23, which is good. But if I do

```
c = Subject.first    # Any subject
s = c.students
s.size          # It returns 1, so it does have AR, and I can see the users.
s.class         # For some reason it is an Array, not an AR, but rails is probably lying
s.destroy_all   # Shows it destroys it successfully

s               # Returns []
c.students      # Returns []
```

But the problem is when I call

```
User.count   # It still return 23
```

The count is wrong. It should be 22. And I can still use User.find(delete_student_id)
and still see the record. It isn't a caching issue when I user Use.count because I use User.all.size, it is gives 23.

I want the student is actually be deleted from the database, using subject.students.destroy_all

For now I'm using

```
User.where(id: s.pluck('users.id')).destroy_all
```

or

```
s.each do |student|
  student.destroy
end
```

Those will work but is a big code smell to me.

Comment: s is the array of user/students, what do you mean?

Comment: [Documentation of destroy_all](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation/destroy_all) (or [destroy_all](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all)) is on @sonnyhe2002's side. As the code fragments are quite short currently my best bet would be a [transaction](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods) preventing the change to be persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`destroy_all` does delete the enrollments only as mikerz suggested. I recreated your setup and ran rails console:

```
>> Subject.first.students.destroy_all
Subject Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `subjects`.* FROM `subjects` LIMIT 1
User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `enrollments` ON `users`.`id` = `enrollments`.`student_id` WHERE `enrollments`.`subject_id` = 1
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  Enrollment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `enrollments`.* FROM `enrollments` WHERE `enrollments`.`subject_id` = 1 AND `enrollments`.`student_id` = 1
  SQL (22.0ms)  DELETE FROM `enrollments` WHERE `enrollments`.`id` = 2
   (91.0ms)  COMMIT
[#<User id: 1, name: "a user", created_at: "2014-02-24 21:49:05", updated_at: "2014-02-24 21:49:05">]
```

So while by contract the deleted objects are returned it seems a bit off for `:through` associations. Leaving you with

```
Subject.first.students.select.destroy_all
```

(where select is the magic to switch to deleting user),

```
Subject.first.students.each { |student| student.destroy }
```

and

```
User.destroy_all(id: Subject.first.students.collect { |student| student.id })
```

And as there is a `depent: :destroy` the first two of those three seem to run the identical number of SQLs while the third will load each `User` twice.
Each variant destroys one enrollment and one user at a time and not all enrollments (not even those by a single user) or all users in one statment. This behaviour is described in [destroy_all](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all)-API doc:

> Note: Instantiation, callback execution, and deletion of each record can be time consuming when you’re removing many records at once. It generates at least one SQL DELETE query per record (or possibly more, to enforce your callbacks). If you want to delete many rows quickly, without concern for their associations or callbacks, use delete_all instead.

Comment: The select.destroy_all, is acceptable. The others, you can use pluck instead of collect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `Enrollment` class to dependent destroy the User:

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :student, class_name 'User', dependent: :destroy
end
```

However, I would not recommend doing this as it will throw an error anytime a `User` is enrolled in multiple `Subjects`.

If you want to delete any `User` not enrolled, I would use an `after_destroy` callback on `Enrollment`.

Comment: That does, destroy the students. but If Subject is destroyed or enrollment is destroyed, then the student is destroyed, which I can not allow. For now I'm doing students.each{|student| student.destroy }